# getString of HttpRequest Being Sent on Android

Tags: android, http

Is there a way I can take an [HttpGet](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html) object and see the *exact* text that will be sent over the wire?

I'm using [ThreadSafeClientConnManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/ThreadSafeClientConnManager.html) when I create my HttpClient.

HttpGet doesn't override `toString()` and the default headers aren't there when I call `HttpGet.getAllHeaders()`.

Comment: Are you talking about seeing whats in the response?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `HttpMethod`'s `headerIterator()` method? It returns a `HeaderIterator` which is described as follows:

> Iterator that returns Header objects
>   in the sequence they are sent over a
>   connection.

The method is contained in the same class as `getAllHeaders()` (the superclass), but it's worth a shot. Also you may want to take a look at using a traffic monitor such as Fiddler to verify that you're correct in your header assumptions.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get the same return as getAllHeaders(). I.e., I get nothing back.